# Chemical Equilibrium and Sponteneity

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

Consider the reaction $$\ce{N2O4 <=> 2 NO2}.$$ The forward direction of this reaction is non-spontaneous and under standard conditions $\Delta G^\circ = \pu{4.76 kJ/mol}$. Suppose we begin with $\pu{1.00 bar}$ of $\ce{N2O4}$ and no products. Then, we would expect the reaction to proceed to equilibrium in which some small concentration of products is formed. I am struggling to understand why it is not a contradiction that the reaction is non-spontaneous, but still proceeds in the forward direction (which indicates that the forward direction is spontaneous).

Comment: Because the criterion of a negative value of standard Gibbs free energy change to signify a spontaneous reaction is only a rule of thumb.

Comment: @Johnny Smith, the spontaneity criterium is $\Delta G > 0$. Just recall that  $ \Delta G = \Delta G^0 + \ln Q$$

Comment: @PAEP do you mean $\Delta G <0$? Also, doesn't assuming that the reactant begins with a partial pressure of 1 bar mean that $\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ$ or am I missing something. I appolgize in advance if this is a very stupid question.

Comment: "standard conditions" mean that there is 1 bar of products as well as reactants.  $\Delta G^\circ >0$ simply means that the net reaction is from products to reactants when all start at 1 bar.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\Delta G^0 <0$. As @Andrew pointed, your initial conditions do not correspond to standard conditions.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: @PAEP You likely meant $\Delta G^\circ < 0$ because $\Delta G^0 \equiv 1.$

Comment: See this answer also   https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173788/can-free-energy-of-a-spontaneous-reaction-be-positive/173805#173805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reaction will proceed to achieve an equilibrium state, this only happens when some amount of both reactants and products are present.

---

Consider a general reaction:

$$
\sum_ir_i\ce{R}_i \ce{->} \sum_jp_j\ce{P}_j
$$

The equilibrium constant is given by:

$$
K = \dfrac{\prod_{j}[\ce{P}_j]_\text{eq}^{p_j}}{\prod_i[{\ce{R}_{i}}]_\text{eq}^{r_i}}
$$

If no product is formed then:

$$
\prod_{j}[\ce{P}_j]_\text{eq}^{p_j} = 0 \implies K = 0
$$

Calculating the free energy for such a reaction:

$$
\Delta G^\circ = -\mathrm{R}T\ln{K}
\implies \lim_{K \rightarrow 0} \Delta G^\circ = \infty
$$

Thus, for a process in which no products are formed, the standard free energy is infinity, which isn't logical, and some products are always formed, regardless of whether the reaction is spontaneous, $\Delta G^\circ <0$, or non-spontaneous, $\Delta G^\circ >0$.

Comment: Is this the thinking that caused the alchemists to fail in turning Pb into Au? There never was any product! Now the reason is clear!  DeltaG = +infinity